# Issue with Nginx and DNS

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, virtualhost

I have a Wordpress running on Nginx, I did all the installation it by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) from Digital Ocean. I used "example.com" domain (literally) to install everything and then, in order to have access to the site, I modified my hosts file locally and redirect the traffic from "example.com" to my server IP. Doing that I was able to access and work on the Wordpress site.

I had an old website (and a domain) which was hosted on another server, so I decided to use that domain for my new Wordpress. What I did was to change the DNS to point to my new server, where Nginx is running and I did all the changes needed to the Nginx Server Blocks (VH) so they matched with the new domain and not with "example.com", but after one day I keep getting this message:

"Example domain. This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission."

I know that DNS propagation could take between some minutes to 48h, but I've checked with an online tool and they are already pointing to the Nginx server IP address, so I don't know what's happening here...

Hope I've explained well... Thanks so much!

Comment: WordPress is aware of the domain it is running on (stored in its database). You would need to change that to match the new domain in order for it to work again. Google "wordpress changing website name" for some guidance on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @parkamark, do you know how to fix media broken links all at once? They are still trying to access "example.com", even after changing the site url and wordpress url...

Comment: You can use any search & replace tool for multiple files to replace the URLs in files. However, it is best to make sure you use domain and protocol relative URLs in the code like `<img src="/path/to/image.png">`, so that you don't have this problem later on.